# integrating $ \frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x-4\sin x+12} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I tried to solve $ \int \frac{\cos x\ dx}{\sin^2 x-4\sin x+12} $ in the following way:

Let $ t = \sin x $. Therefore $ dt = \cos x dx $, which means:

$ \int \frac{\cos x \ dx}{\sin^2 x-4\sin x+12} = \int \frac{1}{t^2-4t+12}dt = \int \frac{1}{t^2-4t+12}dt = \int \frac{1}{(t-2)^2+8}dt = 8 \int \frac{1}{\frac{1}{8}(t-2)^2+1}dt = 8\int \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(t-2))^2+1}dt =8\arctan((\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(t-2))) + C = 8\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(\sin x-2)) +C $.

But this is not the correct answer. Can you give me a hint where I'm wrong?

Comment: I would suggest partial fractions rather than a tangent substitution.  Not that the trig substitution is wrong, it is just more cumbersome.  However, it may give a different-looking answer (one with a logarithm).  However, the difference may actually amount to only a constant.

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{(t-2)^2+8}dt ≠ 8 \int \frac{1}{\frac{1}{8}(t-2)^2+1}dt$

Answer (score 1):

The fourth equality is incorrect. The factor outside the integral should be $1/8$, not $8$. This is the first error I noticed.

Comment: What other errors did you notice?

Answer (score 0):

And idea:

$$\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x-4\sin x+12}dx=\int\frac{\cos x}{(\sin x-2)^2+8}dx=$$

$$=\frac18\int\frac{\cos x}{1+\left(\frac{\sin x-2 }{\sqrt8}\right)^2}=\frac1{\sqrt8}\int\frac{d\left(\frac{\sin x-2}{\sqrt8}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{\sin x-2 }{\sqrt8}\right)^2}=\arctan\left(\frac{\sin x-2}{\sqrt8}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

**Answers**
$$F(x)=\int\;\frac {\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)－4\sin(x)＋12}dx$$
Let  : $$u = \sin(x)\implies du = \cos(x) dx$$

Then :
$$F(x)=\int\;\frac {du}{u^2-4u＋12}＝\int\;\frac {du}{(u－2)^2＋8}$$

Let : $$t=u-2 \implies dt = du$$

Then :
$$F(x)=\int\;\frac {1}{t^2＋8}dt=\textstyle\frac {1}{\sqrt {8}}\tan^{-1}(\frac {t}{\sqrt {8}})＋c$$

finally :
$$F(x)=\textstyle\frac {1}{\sqrt {8}}\tan^{-1}(\frac {t}{\sqrt {8}})＋c＝\textstyle\frac {1}{\sqrt {8}}\tan^{-1}(\frac {u－2}{\sqrt {8}})＋c＝\textstyle\frac {1}{\sqrt {8}}\tan^{-1}(\frac {\sin(x)－2}{\sqrt {8}})＋c$$